# Adding new <li> element into <ul> Questions

Tags: javascript, html

this is my html code

```js
function addChildren() {
  var el = document.getElementById('one');

  //Create new node and textNode
  var newEl = document.createElement('li');
  var newText = document.createTextNode('New Node Text');

  //Append as child Node
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  newEl.setAttribute('class', 'hot');

  //Append as child Node to the last of list
  el.appendChild(newEl);

  //Append as child node to the beginning of list
  el.insertBefore(newEl, el.firstChild);
}

document.querySelector('#add').
  addEventListener('click', addChildren);
```

```html
<ul id='one'>
  <li class='hot'>Hello</li>
  <li class='hot'>World</li>
  <li class='hot'>This</li>
  <li class='hot'>Is</li>
  <li class='hot'>Ben!</li>
</ul>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Why is the script only executing 1 insertion of the new element, although I put in 2 (insertBefore and appendChild)?

And when I tried adding multiple 'appendChild()' method, only 1 new element is added, why is this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add the same node in two places, so the last one wins. The node is actually added to the end, but immediately moved to the start.

You can [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the node, and insert the clone to the start:

```js
function addChildren() {
  var el = document.getElementById('one');

  //Create new node and textNode
  var newEl = document.createElement('li');
  var newText = document.createTextNode('New Node Text');

  //Append as child Node
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  newEl.setAttribute('class', 'hot');

  //Append as child Node to the last of list
  el.appendChild(newEl);

  // create a clone of the node
  var clone = newEl.cloneNode(true);
  
  //Append the clone as child node to the beginning of list
  el.insertBefore(clone, el.firstChild);
}

document.querySelector('#add').
  addEventListener('click', addChildren);
```

```html
<ul id='one'>
  <li class='hot'>Hello</li>
  <li class='hot'>World</li>
  <li class='hot'>This</li>
  <li class='hot'>Is</li>
  <li class='hot'>Ben!</li>
</ul>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```